# Why isn't it possible to track down illegal websites?

Tags: routing, ip, internet

I keep reading about this impregnable illegal website network on the internet.

for a this instance we assume that the co-operation and willingness of legal authority is not a hurdle and everything is in terms of technical designs alone.

1. website servers can't be located due to use of proxies: but proxies are just a relay point which should have a record of the actual user ip that was using the proxy and even if there was a chain of proxy each proxy server should know the address of the last which will track down to the server in the end.
2. There are millions of server running billions of websites: still each website needs a public ip which is unique and dependent  on geological location of the server's isp and the information regarding location of the server can be procured from the isp.
3. websites like pirates bay use virtual machine running on servers: that doesn't explain how it hides the actual location since virtual machine is bound to have a actual hardware for networking which even though having different ip that virtual machine is still a public ip alloted by a isp

Comment: See Also: *tor*

Comment: the pirate bay uses multiple proxies through providers and countries that *do not* cooperate with attempts to trace them down.

Comment: As currently stated your question is too broad to be answered. Either it has too many possible answers or a good answer would be too long for this format. Please [edit] your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. But in summary, either they use countries where such content is not illegal or that don't cooperate, or they use technologies developed specifically to make it hard/impossible to track.